# Problems with source() command after loading XML package

Tags: r

After loading the `XML` package the `source()` command quits with the following error:

```
> require(XML)
Lade nötiges Paket: XML
> source ("test.R")
error in source("test.R") : 
  7 arguments passed to .Internal(identical) which requires 6
```

If I execute `source()` before loading the package it works fine. Any idea how to fix this?

More information:

```
> traceback()
2: source("test.html")
1: source("test.html")

> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Austria.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Austria.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=German_Austria.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] XML_3.9-4.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.15.0
```

Thx,
Fabian

**Edit:** Seems to work with R 2.15.1

Comment: I just installed the XML package and used it for the first time. But now I upgraded to R 2.15.1 and it seems to work.

Comment: Yes this was an issue with 2.15.0 and windows (maybe other platforms).  I don't know if it's officially documented but I discovered this a while back and discovered the, then, development version of 2.15.1 did not produce this result.